# Why do absolutely positioned "content editable" elements shift other absolute elements inside an overflow:hidden element?

Tags: html, css, css-position, overflow, css-transforms

I noticed that when you have multiple absolute elements inside an `overflow:hidden` div with x,y transforms applied and if one of those elements is a content editable element, then as the content grows outside of the overflow it will shift the elements.

From my understanding absolute elements that move around on the x,y plane position should be respected and content that goes out of the overflow div will simply be masked away. This is not the case with content editable.

Why is this? What are some suggested ways to solve this?

Here is a concise fiddle to see what I mean

https://jsfiddle.net/eojx5u3g/15/

Here is a video demonstrating what I am seeing

https://www.loom.com/share/213054f03e8148ea8c456df00e13656b

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to have scrolling for the y-axis.

Then it can be solved by adding `overflow-y: scroll`.
If you want more info on this property please refer this [MDN Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y)

And I noticed that if the word size is more than the width of the container, there also the same problem encountered in x-axis.

so the `overflow-wrap: anywhere` option is to solve this problem

Solution link:
https://jsfiddle.net/cfen924z/

Comment: This is useful, not the best solution. I inspected the code of some major tools that do this and they unmount the textbox and place it on top of the overflow during the edit. Then remount it back in the normal content flow when done.

I am going to follow this approach. Will share a fiddle soon.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback. I am a novice so, it helps me to know more.
@MichaelJosephAurby

Comment: No it's a good solution, the solution I found is not intuitive but it is smart. You basically create a layer on top of the canvas during edit, then send the edited version back into the normal flow.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelJosephAubry for the follow up.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry I still have doubt about how they wrap and put scrolling effect without these rule in css even with a layer on top of it

Comment: Here is the result of this approach. A live demo of the implementation working inside my app https://share.getcloudapp.com/Wnur1lkw

Comment: can you share the snippet of the code used for the layer.